# How to create a dynamic loop for Excel creation in PHPExcel through PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a simple PHP DB Query which generates simple 2 column records. All I have to do is to pass them to PHPExcel sheet object.

This is my PHPExcel code:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


$objWorksheet->fromArray(
    array(
        array('My Page Report 1', 14),
        array('My Page Report 2', 12),
        array('My Page Report 3', 7),
        array('My Page Report 4', 5),
        array('My Page Report 5', 4),
        array('My Page Report 6', 2),
        array('My Page Report 7 ', 1),
        array('My Page Report 8', 1),
        array('My Page Report 9', 1)
    )
);
```

which creates a perfect Pie Chart.

Now I have a simple query whose data I need to pass into this Excel. It's as follows:-

```
$result = db_query("
    SELECT
      n.title, n.nid,
      COUNT(*) AS times
    FROM
      {node_view_count} a, {node} n where a.nid = n.nid AND a.uid = :uid
    GROUP BY
      n.title
    ORDER BY
      times desc",
    array(':uid'=>$_GET['uid'])) -> fetchAll();



    foreach($result as $r) {    
        $resultstr_pages_visited[] = $r->title.", ".$r->times;
     }


// This creates exactly this kind of line
// 'My Page Report 9', 1 and puts a comma to the end.
implode("," , $resultstr_pages_visited);
```

My question is how can I pass this format of data through my loop dynamically into PHPExcel code.

### Print_r results for $resultstr_pages_visited are :-

```
Array ( [0] => 
    Array 
    ( [0] => My Page Report 1 , 14 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 2, 12 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 3, 7 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 4, 5 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 5, 4 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 6, 2 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 7 , 1 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 8, 1 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [0] => My Page Report 9, 1 ) 
    )
```

Comment: looks tome like you could just do: `$objWorksheet->fromArray($resultstr_pages_visited);`

Comment: Thank you Dagon, but it has listed everything in a new column, whereas I want it to list it in every new row. So now, all I have is one row and nine columns with each value in it. Any idea where I am wrong? Thanks.

Comment: ahh i see ok this should work: `$resultstr_pages_visited[] = array($r->title,$r->times);`

Comment: So some progress. It's on multiple rows perfectly, but instead of being in two columns, it's in one column. As an example, My Report Page 1 should be in first column and 14 should be in second column but right now it is `My Report Page 1, 14` in one column. Any idea?

Comment: `print_r($resultstr_pages_visited)`; and post the results

Comment: :(. It just shows `Array` in all cells now. This time, they all are showing as columns instead of rows again :( Let me post my print_r results.

Comment: Print_r results posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$row = 1;
foreach($result as $r) {
    $objWorksheet->fromArray(array($r->title, $r->times), null, 'A'.$row);
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: :( It gives this error `PHPExcel_Exception: Parameter $source should be an array. in PHPExcel_Worksheet->fromArray() (line 2413 of /sites/default/excel_library/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php).`

Comment: $r should be an array if your SQL query returns an array of arrays as your print_r output suggests.... though it's a very odd looking array for the result of a SQL query, it's unbalanced

Comment: Thank you Mark. But that was due to this line that was requested by Dagon to add. `$resultstr_pages_visited[] = array($r->title.", ".$r->times);`. Since I changed the loop to your code, it's not an array anymore. I'll be grateful if you could please tweak the code to cater with this error.